# Find total memory used by Python process and all its children

Tags: python, memory, process, parallel-processing, fork

How can I find the total amount of resident memory used by a Python process **and all its forked children**?

I know that I can use `psutil`, for example, to find the percentage of a available physical memory used by the current process like so:

```
import os
import psutil
current_process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
mem = current_process.memory_percent()
```

But I'm looking for the total memory used by a process and its children, if it has any.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the result from `psutil.Process.children()` (or `psutil.Process.get_children()` for older psutil versions) to get all child processes and iterate over them.
It could then look like:

```
import os
import psutil
current_process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
mem = current_process.memory_percent()
for child in current_process.children(recursive=True):
    mem += child.memory_percent()
```

This would sum the percentages of memory used by the main process, its children (forks) and any children's children (if you use `recursive=True`). You can find this function in the [current psutil docs](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.children) or the [old docs](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation).

If you use an older version of psutil than 2 you have to use `get_children()` instead of `children()`.

Comment: Simply `psutil.Process()` was equivalent to `psutil.Process(os.getpid())` for me with `psutil==5.6.3`.

Comment: Watch out! `psutil.Process.memory_percent()` could rise an `psutil.NoSuchProcess` exception if the child process is not alive anymore.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the [resource](https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html#resource.getrusage) library.  Here's the memory and other resource info for a single process:

### source

```
# https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html#resource.getrusage

import resource, time

pagesize = resource.getpagesize()
info = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF)

print 'EMPTY:', info
print info.ru_maxrss * pagesize, 'bytes'

beer = open('/vmlinuz').read(), 'bytes'

info=resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF)
print
print 'FULL:', info
print info.ru_maxrss * pagesize, 'bytes'
```

### output

```
EMPTY: resource.struct_rusage(ru_utime=0.011235, ru_stime=0.0037449999999999996, ru_maxrss=4872, ru_ixrss=0, ru_idrss=0, ru_isrss=0, ru_minflt=1448, ru_majflt=0, ru_nswap=0, ru_inblock=0, ru_oublock=0, ru_msgsnd=0, ru_msgrcv=0, ru_nsignals=0, ru_nvcsw=0, ru_nivcsw=4)
19955712 bytes

FULL: resource.struct_rusage(ru_utime=0.013916, ru_stime=0.004638, ru_maxrss=10380, ru_ixrss=0, ru_idrss=0, ru_isrss=0, ru_minflt=2824, ru_majflt=0, ru_nswap=0, ru_inblock=0, ru_oublock=0, ru_msgsnd=0, ru_msgrcv=0, ru_nsignals=0, ru_nvcsw=0, ru_nivcsw=4)
42516480 bytes
```

The `ru_idrss` number is `maximum resident set size` in pages. Multiply that by the page size in bytes to get the maximum amount of memory used by the parent process.

Repeating the above, specifying `RUSAGE_CHILDREN`, will give children's memory usage.

Note the above is pretty rough, but gives some idea of what's happening.

Comment: Please, note: you cannot rely on getpagesize(), as getrusage() returns data aligned to 1 KiB, while page can usually has size of 4 KiB